# Unhandled Rejection (Error): call revert exception problem in ethersjs with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to make a decentralized voting system and so I cloned this repo. I followed the instructions for it. I installed the dependencies, ran the deploy script while also running a hardhat node on a parallel terminal.
[link to the repo](https://github.com/haechi00/vote-system)

I think this is happening because I am supposed to change other things as well maybe the abi or contract address. I am new to this field. Could someone guide me as to what all changes should I make to the cloned project to make it run locally as well?

here is the deploy script-

```
async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log('Deploying contracts with the account:', deployer.address);

    console.log('Account balance:', (await deployer.getBalance()).toString());

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Ballot');
    const token = await Token.deploy([
        '0x696d70726f76652d64656d6f6372616379000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x6b6565702d64656d6f6372616379000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x676f6f642d6469746163746f7200000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '0x616e617263687900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    ]);

    console.log('Token address:', token.address);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

and the react code-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { ethers } from 'ethers';

import CheckVoterAddress from './CheckVoterAddress';
import Proposals from './Proposals';
import AddVoter from './AddVoter';

import TokenArtifact from '../ABI/Ballot.json';
import contractAddress from '../ABI/contract-address.json';

export const Dapp = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState();
    const [newVoter, setNewVoter] = useState('');
    const [newVoterStatus, setNewVoterStatus] = useState('');
    const [voterStatus, setVoterStatus] = useState();
    const [voterAddressToCheck, setVoterAddressToCheck] = useState('');
    const [proposals, setProposals] = useState([]);
    const [chairperson, setChairperson] = useState('');

    // **************** Ethers Connection for the SmartContract ****************

    async function _initialize() {
        await _intializeEthers();
    }

    const _intializeEthers = async () => {
        // ethers connection for the smartcontract
        const _provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

        const _token = new ethers.Contract(
            contractAddress.Token,
            TokenArtifact.abi,
            _provider.getSigner(0)
        );

        // get the proposals
        const newProposal = await _token.getAllProposals();

        // get the chairman address
        const newChairperson = await _token.chairperson();

        // save the token data into a hook to reuse it along the app
        setToken(_token);
        setProposals(newProposal);
        setChairperson(newChairperson);
    };

    // Connects to the smart contract token id (check /contracts/contract-address.json)
    async function init() {
        const [selectedAddress] = await window.ethereum.enable();
        _initialize(selectedAddress);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // When the page loads it will initialize the init function
        // that we need to connect the frontend with the smartcontract
        init();
    }, []);

    // **************** Here Starts The Real Logic of the Frontend -> SmartContract ****************

    // Vote the selected proposal (you can only vote one time)
    const voteProposal = async (proposal) => {
        await token.vote(proposal);
    };

    // Check if the address the user entered is a a voter or not
    const checkAddressVoter = async () => {
        try {
            const voterData = await token.voters(`${voterAddressToCheck}`);
            setVoterStatus(voterData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setVoterStatus('An error has occured');
        }
    };

    // It gives the right to vote to a new address
    const addNewVoter = async () => {
        try {
            await token.giveRightToVote(newVoter);
            setNewVoterStatus('Success');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setNewVoterStatus('An error has occured');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: '3rem 5rem' }}>
            <h1>Voting System</h1>
            <div>
                <h4>chairperson: {chairperson}</h4>
            </div>
            <Proposals proposals={proposals} voteProposal={voteProposal} />
            <AddVoter
                addNewVoter={addNewVoter}
                setNewVoter={setNewVoter}
                newVoter={newVoter}
                newVoterStatus={newVoterStatus}
            />
            <CheckVoterAddress
                voterAddressToCheck={voterAddressToCheck}
                setVoterAddressToCheck={setVoterAddressToCheck}
                checkAddressVoter={checkAddressVoter}
                voterStatus={voterStatus}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```